# Azure devops pipeline not using updated version of custom task from visual studio marketplace

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use a custom task that I uploaded to the Visual Studio Marketplace. Below in this picture I made, you can see the version is 0.0.25 but the pipeline is using an older version of 0.0.23. [image: marketplace and pipeline]

I checked in my azure devops at the organization level, if I go to the organization settings and go to extensions, I see the latest version is also 0.0.25
[image: org level settings]

is there anything I'm missing here in order for the pipeline to use the correct version?

I tried creating a new pipeline and using different pipelines, tried removing the code changes I made and republishing a new version, all still used the same 0.0.23 version.

Comment: Sometimes something goes wrong inside Azure DevOps when pushing the tasks from the extension into the Azure DevOps org. Installing the extension is a 2-step process. 1. it installs the extension into the organization. 2. It extracts the tasks from the extension and pushes those into the Project Collection. The 2nd step sometimes misfires and there is a nightly job that tries to fix that. You can sometimes force this job to run by uninstalling the extension from the organization and reinstalling it. Also be sure that both the extension and the tasks in the extension have a higher version number

Comment: Another thing that may be happening is that a private agent is failing to download a new version from the org. It may use a cached version. You can force a download by deleting the `_tasks` folder in the agent's working directory.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I want to try out the second comment you made first, could you tell me how to navigate to the _tasks folder for the agent? I went to project settings > agent pools > clicked on my agent pool > went to agents tab. I wasn't able to find any sort of working directory?

Comment: You have to actually remote desktop / ssh into the agent. If you're on a Hosted Agent, this won't apply to you.

Comment: found the answer, turns out I had to update the version also in the task.json file, this being a custom powershell task